# Strange message when analyzing code in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, message, code-analysis

I have a array which I fill with values from checkboxes, sliders and an NSTextField. 
See below 001. And it´s working obviously.

However, when analyzing my code I get this message:

`/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/Egg&Breakfast/Classes/TimeController.m:358:24: 
Argument to 'NSArray' method 'arrayWithObjects:' 
should be an Objective-C pointer type, not 'NSInteger'`

I tried several things like type casting the three lines with intValue to (NSInteger). Without success. Any idea what´s wrong?

```
NSArray *myValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [isAppointment state],     //Checkbox
                    [boxForEver    state],     //Checkbox
                    [boxMakeSound  state],     //Checkbox
                    [tickTackFlag  state],     //Checkbox
                    [txtRemark   stringValue], //NSTextField
                    [slideHour      intValue], //Slider
                    [slideMin       intValue], //Slider
                    [slideSec       intValue], //Slider
                    [startAuto     state],     //Checkbox
                    nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the lines that call `state` or `intValue` are incorrect.

An `NSArray` can only hold references to Objective-C objects.  But `state` and `intValue` return `NSInteger`, which is a typedef (alias) for `long`, which is C primitive, not an Objective-C object reference.

You need to wrap the integers in `NSNumber` objects.  If you're using Xcode 4.4 or later, you can just use the new `@(...)` wrapper syntax to wrap your integers in `NSNumber` objects.  You can also use the new array literal syntax `@[...]` to construct your array.

```
NSArray *myValues = @[
                    @([isAppointment state]),     //Checkbox
                    @([boxForEver    state]),     //Checkbox
                    @([boxMakeSound  state]),     //Checkbox
                    @([tickTackFlag  state]),     //Checkbox
                    [txtRemark   stringValue], //NSTextField
                    @([slideHour      intValue]), //Slider
                    @([slideMin       intValue]), //Slider
                    @([slideSec       intValue]), //Slider
                    @([startAuto     state]),     //Checkbox
                    ];
```

Comment: Great explanations and suggestions. That worked fine. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert scalar types such as `int`, `float` or `NSInteger` into `NSArray`.

You must insert pointers to `NSObject` or subclasses, as mentioned in the error message.

A common way to prevent that shortcoming is to use [`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

For instance :

```
NSInteger foo = 42;
[_myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:foo]];
```

On recent Xcode versions, you can use a bit of syntactic sugar

```
[_myArray addObject:@42];
```